# Custom feature map with complex features in the Qiskit VQC

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I am trying to use the VQC in Qiskit and create a custom feature map. To build the feature map I am using from qiskit.circuit the class [ParameterVector](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.components.feature_maps.FeatureMap.html), but this class does not let me use complex features.

Do you know any way I can still use the VQC while using the complex features?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article can help you: 'Automatic design of quantum feature maps', Sergio Altares-López, Angela Ribeiro and Juan José García-Ripoll, 19 August 2021 - https://doi.org/10.1088/2058-9565/ac1ab1.

They describe a technique to generate optimal quantum feature maps by using multiobjetive genetic algorithms. While the first objective is to increase the accuracy in the predictions on unseen data, building robust classifiers with generalisation power; the second objective of this technique is to reduce the complexity of the quantum circuits.

In this study they use 22 features in a quantum model.